# groovy map operation not giving expected value

Tags: groovy, scripting

I am trying to find duplicate tags in an xml file. and i wrote the following:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parse('myfile.xml')
List<String> intNames =  xml.depthFirst().findAll {
    it.name() == 'InternalName'
}

println "Total:" + intNames.size()
```

// println "Unique:" + intNames.unique().size()

```
def map = [:]

for(itm in intNames){
    if(map.get(itm) == null)
        map.put(itm, 1)
    else{
        def val = map.get(itm)
        map.put(itm, val + 1)
        println itm
    }
}


    println "map size: ${map.size()}"
```

The result shows as:

```
Total:13811
map size: 13811
```

if i uncomment the line

```
// println "Unique:" + intNames.unique().size()
```

then it looks like

```
Total:13811
Unique:13792
map size: 13792
```

So, if unique has less number of values then why else clause is not able to print anything?

Comment: `intNames` is  not a collection of String, it's a collection of Node ?

Comment: i think that explains

Comment: Does xml have namespace prefix?